# Edit Grid.RowDefination programmatically in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

As the title, I set the row definition of the grid in XAML file first. But in the code behind I want to change it in some case. So do we have any way to do it? Can we do something like this

```
grid_socket.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
```

Comment: Do you want to add more rows to grid or you want to set any control in particular row?

Comment: RowDefination and ColumnDefinations are used to define row/columns in grid.

Comment: Assume I had two row.defination already, now I want to edit the properties of the first row defination. is it ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access `RowHeight` properties accessing `Grid.RowDefinitions` property. For example setting the first row height to `2*`:

```
MyGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Alternatively you can name a particular row definition:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition x:Name="FirstRow" />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And then access it code via `FirstRow` directly.